Finding a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Consider the subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ of $\Bbb R^3$  given by
$W_1=\{(x,y,z) \in\Bbb R^3: x+y+z= 0\}$ and
$W_2=\{(x, y, z)\in\Bbb R^3: x-y+z=0\}$.
If $W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ such that:
(i) $W\cap W_2=\text{span}\{(0,1,1)\}$
(ii) $W\cap W_1$ is orthogonal to $W\cap W_2$ with respect to the usual inner product of $\Bbb R^3$,then find $W$.

My attempt:
From condition (i), $(0,1,1)\in W$.
Now if $(x,y,z)\in W\cap W_1$ then $x+y+z=0$...(1) and $\langle (x,y,z),(0,1,1)\rangle$=$0$ (by condition (ii)) $\implies y+z=0$...(2)
Solving (1) and (2) we get $x=0$ & $y=-z$.
Thus $$W\cap W_1\subseteq\{(x,y,z)∈\Bbb R^3:x=0,y=−z\}=\text{span}\{(0,1,−1)\}.$$
So,  $W\cap W_1$ is either the line $\text{span}\{(0,1,−1)\}$ or $\{0\}$.
Now how to proceed from here in order to find $W$?

You already proved that $(0,1,1)\in W$, and that $W\cap W_1$ is either null-subspace or the line spanned by $(0,1,−1)$.

If $W\cap W_1=\{\vec0_{\Bbb R^3}\}$, then $\dim W\le 3-\dim W_1=1$ hence $W$ is the line spanned by $(0,1,1)$.

If $(0,1,−1)\in W$ then $W$ contains the plane spanned by $(0,1,−1)$ and $(0,1,1)$. It is therefore equal to that plane, because $W\ne\Bbb R^3$ since $W\cap W_2\ne W_2$.

Follow up after your recent addition of proposed answers: in view of the solution above, answers 2, 3 and 4 are blatlantly wrong, but answer 1 is not quite correct because $W$ is not necessarily a plane.

You re-edited your post, essentially copying my solution above, and asking at the end whether it is correct, (i.e. whether it is true that $W$ is not necessarily a plane but can as well be a line). I maintain it can. $W=\text{span}\{(0,1,1)\}$ satisfies (i) and (ii).


